# How To Fix: Invalid "database" config. "local" is not defined inside "connections". Make sure to set it inside the "config/database" file Adonis Js

Tags: node.js, npm, redis, adonis.js

I got an exception from Redis it says:
**Invalid "database" config. "local" is not defined inside "connections". Make sure to set it inside the "config/database" file.**


To Implement Throttle. I download Two Packages:
**1) Adonis-Request-Throttler**

```
yarn add adonis-request-throttler
```

**2) Redis**

```
yarn add @adonisjs/redis
```

And ConfigureThen as the instruction shown in Adonis Js Official Documentation.

```
node ace configure @adonisjs/packagename
```

I also pest **Validate environment variables** in **env.ts** file. But When I try to run my app I got an exception :

[image: Redis Exception]

**Please Help me To Fix This. I have tried everything but it's not working and my project is is running.**

Answer (score 0):

That problem is because your config/database file is not properly configured.

Set the variables as recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/introduction) depending on which database driver you are using.